# i have updated android sdk. But after updation it shows the error in android-support-v4

Tags: android, eclipse

Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

QuizApp] Versions found are:

```
 Path: D:\Android\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
    Length: 627582
    SHA-1: db0f122c99ef9f90dbab3fada6d191f2880cbb8e
 Path: D:\Android\workspace\QuizApp\libs\android-support-v4.jar
 QuizApp]   Length: 648327
    SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: Try remove jar from your project which is already available in your support library.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Support Library And then

1)Right click on 'free' project > Android Tools > Add Support Library.
2)Do the same thing on 'paid' project.
3)Clean all projects

Answer (score 0):

```
It indicates 2 different version of same library android-support-v4.jar.

Do this,
```

- Delete android-support-v4.jar from library and project.
- Then go in /extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos/ and copy android-support-v4.jar and paste in libs folder of both.